# How can I improve my print quality?

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura, petg

Printing on an Ender 3 V2 Neo, using Cura to slice, PETG-filament.

I printed a 3DBenchy and there is a fair bit of stringing and the layers are showing. The roof looks a little bit weird, the printer has printed it in a stairy kind of way. Also there are ripples all over the print.

[image: Image of Benchy with ripples, stringing and layers showing well]

[image: From the back]

[image: From the side]

- 0.4mm Nozzle
- PETG Standard Quality 0.2mm
- Layer Height 0.2mm
- Line Width 0.4mm
- Wall Thickness 2.0mm
- Wall Line Count 5
- Top/Bottom Thickness 0.8
- Infill Density 20%
- Infill Pattern Cubic
- Print Temp 240 Celsius
- Build Plate Temp 80 Celsius
- Flow 97.0%
- Print Speed 50.0 mm/s
- Wall Speed 25.0 mm/s
- Retraction Distance 5.0 mm
- Retraction Speed 45.0 mm/s
- Retract at Layer Change Off
- Retract Before Outer Wall On
- Avoid Supports When Traveling On
- Fan Speed 35.0 %

I am a beginner in 3D printing and haven't spent any time further tuning it than the set-up. Thank you for helping.